# Returning the Index from a Array Object where the Object contains an array

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, object

I have the following code (scaled down) that simulates the races a karting driver takes place in.

I initially start with a two dimensional array for each Driver.

Each driver then has an Object array attached to it that has the rounds competed in.

How can I search through the "round" object array and return both the index of the driver and the index of the round.

This is a scaled down version but by the end their will be a lot more data added so hesitating using a for/next loop;

**For example:**
I want to search each .round object array and return an array containing both the index for the driver and the index of the .round object if they has raced in round 10;

In this case `driver[0][1]` would return the values `[[1][4]];` driver `[[0][3]]` would return the values`[[3][3]]` and `driver[5]` would return the values `[[5][1]]` in a new array;

```
driver = [];
driver[0] = [];

for(n=0; n<=5; n++){
    driver[0][n] = new Object();
    driver[0][n].id = "Driver: "+n;
    driver[0][n].round = new Array();
}

driver[0][0].round = [0];
driver[0][1].round = [1,3,5,7,10];
driver[0][2].round = [1,2,4];
driver[0][3].round = [5,7,8,10,12,14];
driver[0][4].round = [6,11,12];
driver[0][5].round = [4,10,11,12];
```

Thanks in advance.

I can achieve this with a for/next loop but potentially the driver array will become quite large so wanting to know if there is a quicker better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way you could do it:

```
driver = []; 
driver[0] = [];

for(n=0; n<=5; n++){
  driver[0][n] = new Object();
  driver[0][n].id = "Driver: "+n;
  driver[0][n].round = new Array();
}

driver[0][0].round = [0];
driver[0][1].round = [1,3,5,7,10];
driver[0][2].round = [1,2,4];
driver[0][3].round = [5,7,8,10,12,14];
driver[0][4].round = [6,11,12];
driver[0][5].round = [4,10,11,12];

const getRound = (driverIndex, round) => {
    const roundIndex = driver[0][driverIndex].round.indexOf(round);
    return [[driverIndex], [roundIndex >= 0 ? roundIndex : null]];
}

console.log(getRound(0, 10)) // [[0], [null]]
console.log(getRound(1, 10)) // [[1], [4]]
console.log(getRound(2, 10)) // [[2], [null]]
console.log(getRound(3, 10)) // [[3], [3]]
```

I might try to store the driver data in a different way, for example storing the drivers in a key/value object with the driver's ID as the key, for easier access. I guess if the driver's ID is always going to be the same as their index it doesn't matter much, but it makes more sense to me to store them in a key/value object.

Edit:
If you need all indices of the round ->

```
const getRounds = (driverIndex, round) => {
    const roundIndices = [];
    i = -1;
    while ((i = driver[0][driverIndex].round.indexOf(round, i+1)) != -1){
        roundIndices.push(i);
    }
        return [[driverIndex], roundIndices];
}

console.log(getRound(3, 10)) // [[3], [3, 6]]
```

Comment: Thanks.  Out of interest if I one of the driver arrays has two values of 10. i.e,  driver[0][3].round=[5,10,7,10,12,14] how would I return the value so it would be = 5,2,4?

Comment: Made a small typo, in my first answer, should be roundIndex >= 0 (since the round could be in the first index)

Comment: Edited to include a function that gets all indices.

Comment: No problem, don't forget to mark it as answered <3